# Is it possible to loop infinitely with a switch statement?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I am writing a code quality tool. I am scanning source and compiled classes searching for potential infinite loops.

I can't think a way of a souce code switch statement can loop indefinitely. Am I wrong?

Switch statements compile to `lookupswitch` and `tableswitch` opcodes. I will need to check compile classes for security reasons, and also bytecode modifications are allow before the quality control program process the compiled classes. **Having say that, is there a possible way of looping infinitely by using only those opcodes by modifying a class or generating it with assembler?**

I have already taken care of every other branching instructions and statements.

Your help will be really appreciated.

Edit:
Conclusion:

As I suspected and by the answers here provided, a switch statement in source code can only branch forward, but any branching instruction in bytecode could potentially jump backwards (assuming bytecode modifications).

Comment: assuming its in its own method: a case is calling the method with same parameter ?!

Comment: If you can hack bytecode to set the jump address for tableswitch back to the tableswitch instruction itself, you would have yourself a nice infinite loop. Same goes for the lookup switch.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yeah, you are right

Comment: You should also be careful about potential infinite loops with multiple switches. A tableswitch/lookupswitch behaves very much like a collection of `goto`s under the hood.

Comment: But even with multiple switches, I can't think of a possible infinite loop in source code. I have already take care of for, while, call, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Having say that, is there a possible way of looping infinitely by using only those opcodes by modifying a class or generating it with assembler?

To have an infinite loop you have to just backward somewhere.  If you modify the byte code this can happen where ever you add or change a jump to go back. If not it can't be a loop, infinite or otherwise.

Comment: @JuanGarcia in source code you need to have something which will jump back when it is compiled.  There is far more limited options and in the case of `switch` alone it cannot be used as a loop at all so you are safe.

Comment: Just as I though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting that you can do this with bytecode version 1.6 (50), but cannot with bytecode version 1.7 (51) as verification fails. This code (requires ASM5) works correctly and has infinite loop:

```
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.Label;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import static org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.*;

public class LookupTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        new ClassLoader() {
            @Override
            protected Class<?> findClass(String name)
                    throws ClassNotFoundException {
                ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS
                        | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
                // Create public class extending java.lang.Object
                cw.visit(V1_6, ACC_PUBLIC | ACC_SUPER, name, null,
                        "java/lang/Object", null);
                // Create default constructor
                MethodVisitor mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "<init>", "()V",
                        null, null);
                mv.visitCode();
                // Call superclass constructor (this is required)
                mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
                mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/Object", "<init>",
                        "()V", false);
                // Create branch target
                Label target = new Label();
                mv.visitLabel(target);
                // System.out.println("Hello");
                mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out",
                        "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
                mv.visitLdcInsn("Hello");
                mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream",
                        "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
                // switch(0) {
                mv.visitInsn(ICONST_0);
                // default: goto target;
                // }
                mv.visitLookupSwitchInsn(target, new int[0], new Label[0]);
                mv.visitMaxs(-1, -1);
                mv.visitEnd();
                cw.visitEnd();
                byte[] bytes = cw.toByteArray();
                return defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            }
        }.loadClass("LookupGotoTest").newInstance();
    }
}
```

However if you replace `V1_6` with `V1_7`, it fails with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad instruction
Exception Details:
  Location:
    LookupGotoTest.<init>()V @13: lookupswitch
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab7 0008 b200 0e12 10b6 0016 03ab 0000
    0x0000010: ffff fff7 0000 0000                    
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@4,{Object[#2]},{})

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2658)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3062)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
    at LookupTest.main(LookupTest.java:46)
```

However if I make the forward jump instead and add a goto instruction, it works fine even with 1.7 bytecode:

```
Label target2 = new Label();
// switch(0) {
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_0);
// default: goto target2;
// }
mv.visitLookupSwitchInsn(target2, new int[0], new Label[0]);
mv.visitLabel(target2);
// goto target
mv.visitJumpInsn(GOTO, target);
```

The difference appears due to different verification procedure: Java classes prior to Java 1.6 has no StackMapTable and verified by [Type Inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.2), while classes with version 1.7 or higher are verified by [Type Checking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1) which has separate strict rules for individual instructions including [lookupswitch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.lookupswitch).

Currently it's unclear for me whether such instruction is actually not allowed in 1.7+ or ASM just generated incorrect StackMapTable.

---

As @Holger and @apangin noted, this is likely an ASM bug and can be worked around adding at least one case branch via `mv.visitLookupSwitchInsn(target, new int[]{1}, new Label[]{target});`. So in conclusion: yes, you can generate backward branch in switch using any bytecode version.

Comment: I still don’t know whether its an ASM or Verifier issue, but changing it to `mv.visitLookupSwitchInsn(target, new int[]{1}, new Label[]{target});` fixes the problem and makes the infinite loop via switch work with `v51` and `v52`. So it dislikes backward branches only when there are no `case` labels. I wanted to know whether empty switches ever happen and found out that `javac` generates a `pop` for `switch(0){}` while generating an empty switch for `switch(0){default:}`…

Comment: This might be an ASM bug when computing StackMapTable. JVMS allows to have have backward branch targets in `lookupswitch`. Type checking verifier was introduced in bytecode v.50, however, JVM falls back to inferencing verifier if type checking fails. There is no fallback provided for modern class versions.

Comment: @apangin: as said, it works when there are case labels. I’m going to have a look at the generated stackmap now…

Comment: Verified carefully and the generated Stackmaps are correct and identical. So it must be the verifier which dislikes a backward branching switch when there are no `case` labels.

Answer (score 1):

At the bytecode level, everything is gotos, basically. A tableswitch or lookupswitch instruction is just a list of offsets to jump to. You can make it jump backwards if you want. You can't make it jump directly to itself, but that's only because it pops an int off the stack each time. If you prefix it with an int push, you can have a 2 instruction loop.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following source code:

```
public static void main(String... arg) {
    loop: for(;;) switch(arg.length) {
        case 0: continue;
        default: break loop;
    }
}
```

When compiling it with Oracle’s `javac` (jdk1.8), you’ll get

```
public static void main(java.lang.String...)
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: arraylength
     2: lookupswitch  { // 1
                   0: 20
             default: 23
        }
    20: goto          0
    23: goto          26
    26: return
```

This obviously is a straight-forward translation, but this result is not mandatory. The `goto`s at the end are actually obsolete and by compiling with Eclipse 4.4.2, I got:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String...) t
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: arraylength
     2: tableswitch   { // 0 to 0
                   0: 20
             default: 23
        }
    20: goto          0
    23: return
```

So this compiler already omitted one of these obsolete `goto`s. But it’s imaginable that another compiler would even eliminate the other `goto` as well, without changing the semantic:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String...) t
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: arraylength
     2: tableswitch   { // 0 to 0
                   0: 0
             default: 20
        }
    20: return
```

It’s also imaginable that a byte code optimization tool is capable of taking either of the former results and transform it into the third variant. Since this is all without changing the semantic of the code, it’s all still reflecting the valid Java source code shown above.

So having a `switch` bytecode instruction producing a loop doesn’t necessarily represent a logic not reproducible in Java source code. It’s just a compiler implementation dependent property when they never produce such a construct but more redundant code instead. Keep always in mind that both, `while`/`for` loops and `switch` statements, are source code artifacts and not mandating a particular byte code form.

Comment: The goto in the byte code is due to the infinite for(;;). It is that for which that break is part of and not the switch. You could also do this with a while(true) or a do while(true) with probably the same bytecode output

Comment: In the Eclipse generated code, the `goto` belongs to the `continue`, not the `break`, but it doesn’t matter. The point is, *both*  `goto`s can be elided and thus, *in principle* you can generate such byte code with legal Java code (which is what you asked in **bold**). Of course, the source code will always contain a loop statement, but that was not the question.

Comment: Both the continue and the break are part of the for statement in the source code. Your last optimization makes clear that tableswitch can loop backwards. However the source above could have been written with if's and that doesn't proof that if's could be used for infinite loops in source. Of course if's are too branching instructions when compiled, and the same hack can apply.

Comment: Maybe I got your question wrong, but I thought you want to know whether you have to be prepared to encounter such bytecode when analyzing compiled Java code. And my answer is that even without fancy hacking, legal Java code can in principle produce such code, even if current mainstream compiler don't. Of course, the source code will have to have a loop somewhere.